tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
I running
$ cat /etc/*-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="12"
VERSION="12 (bookworm)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bookworm
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"

Unfortunately, I am not able to extract xz file.
$ wget -c https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra_release/releases/stable/linux/flutter_linux_3.19.5-stable.tar.xz
--2024-04-17 11:21:57--  https://storage.googleapis.com/flutter_infra_release/releases/stable/linux/flutter_linux_3.19.5-stable.tar.xz
Resolving storage.googleapis.com (storage.googleapis.com)... 172.217.167.91, 142.250.71.91, 142.250.66.251, ...
Connecting to storage.googleapis.com (storage.googleapis.com)|172.217.167.91|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 665630904 (635M) [application/x-tar]
Saving to: ‘flutter_linux_3.19.5-stable.tar.xz’

flutter_linux_3.19.5-stable.tar.xz   100%[===================================================================>] 634.79M  6.06MB/s    in 1m 55s  

2024-04-17 11:23:53 (5.51 MB/s) - ‘flutter_linux_3.19.5-stable.tar.xz’ saved [665630904/665630904]

$ tar xf flutter_linux_3.19.5-stable.tar.xz /usr/bin/
tar: /usr/bin: Not found in archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

$ sudo tar xf flutter_linux_3.19.5-stable.tar.xz /usr/bin/
tar: /usr/bin: Not found in archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

$ sudo tar -xf flutter_linux_3.19.5-stable.tar.xz /usr/bin/
tar: /usr/bin: Not found in archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

What did I miss?

What is it you're trying to do?  That file is an archive of a git repo based on the flutter directory; if you do a tar tf on the file then you'll see what's in it.  You don't want to extract it all into /usr/bin and there is no file inside it starting with /usr/bin.  If  you want to extract every file into the current directory, just tar xf flutter_linux_3.19.5-stable.tar.xz

@StephenHarris The official installation instructions for this thing are admittedly somewhat confusing concerning the extraction of the archive.  It does not mention using tar and seems to use the archive file itself as an executable: https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/linux/desktop?tab=download  It is also messed up that they seem to imply that this archive (which contains what looks like a cloned Git repository) should be extracted under /usr/bin.

GNU/tar typically throws tar: Removing leading '/' from member names so that restore can always be relative. Having an archive that can only be restored over the existing full directory is evil -- you need to be in '/' deliberately to do that. It is possible your archive will start a directory tree at /usr/bin/newRelativeDir, but it is prudent to always list the ToC of any archive you receive. My office once bricked a Solaris server by restoring a stray AIX archive of /usr/bin instead of the expected data tape.

The -C was missingin sudo tar -xf flutter_linux_3.19.5-stable.tar.xz -C /usr/bin/

I would seriously doubt that extracting that archive into /usr/bin is the correct way of installing that software.  The reason I did not write an answer to this question is that the instructions that I believe that you are following don't make sense and that I believe that they are seriously out of date or just plain wrong.  I would suggest that you extract the archive elsewhere and then look into the extracted archive for further documentation (something I haven't had time to do myself).

... for example, right after saying "the Flutter SDK should be in the /usr/bin/flutter directory" (which seems entirely against the FHS) they tell you to add $HOME/development/flutter/bin to your PATH
